# Finding and wrapping text with tag in another tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a text for an exception result like that:

```
<span class='sException'>Exception throwed. Please check details:
Message:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Stack: at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style) at ... 
</span>
```

I want to wrap some texts(Message:, Stack: and texts between them) with css. So i want to have this as a result:

```
<span class='sException'>Exception throwed. Please check details:
<b>Message:</b><span class='sMessage'>String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.</span>
<b>Stack:</b><span class='stack'> at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style) at ... </span>
</span>
```

Is there any way to do achive this with css ?

something like that:

```
.sException{ text-align:left; border:1px solid red; }
.sException[find text like 'Message:']{ display:block; font-weight:bold; text-indet:20px; }
.sException[find text after 'Message:']{ display:block; font-weight:normal; text-indet:30px; }
.sException[find text like 'Stack:']{ display:block; font-weight:bold; text-indet:20px; }
.sException[find text after 'Stack:']{ display:block; font-weight:normal; text-indet:30px; }
```

Comment: actually i prefer to solve this with css but i don't believe i can. Thats why i added jquery because i think answers will be in jquery.

Comment: css is a markup lanugage. a lot of people confuse it for a functioning language. you can ONLY style things, not create them.

Comment: @contagious - But we can select elements in html with css like input[type=button]{ bla bla ...} if there is something like .ClassName[find('Message:')]{display:block;....} it doesn't mean that css is something like functioning lang.

Answer (score 1):

Css isn't going to generate tags. CSS is to style tags. You'll need to use jquery to parse the contents of `.sException` and format the data

```
$('.sException').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).text();
  if(content.indexOf('Message:') > -1) {
    // wrap in span tags
  }
  // etc
  $(this).html(content);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That can't be done with css alone, you need some `javascript` too.

jQuery:

```
var $sException = $('.sException'),
    _str_msg    = $sException.text();
_str_msg = _str_msg.replace(/(Message:)/g, '<b>$1</b>');

$sException.html(_str_msg);
```

Now you can add a `css class` as well into the replacing string (`<b class="anything">`)